# How to printf all array in C Programming?

Tags: c

i was new with array for C programming. Anybody can help me? I want to print all array that saved from the assignment. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    const char *a[3];
    char s[100];
    int data, i=0;
    back:
    printf("Please insert name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &s);
    a[i] = s;
    printf("Do you want to add data?: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    if (data==1){
        i++;
        goto back;}
    else{
    printf("%s", a[0] , a[1] , a[2]);}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at how to make a loop.

Comment: Don't use `goto` https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: You don't check that `i` exceeds the bounds of the `const char *a[3]` array indexing when repeated.

Comment: Not only that, but all array elements will point to the same string: the most recent entry at `char s[100];`.

Comment: use loop statements instead of using goto.

Comment: 1) `goto` has it's uses, but this is not a reasonable. 2) Don't get creative with formatting of your code. It already is hard to read; a slightlich more complex code will be unreadable, thus unmaintainable!

Comment: I know how to use loop and i use goto to make it easier but in here what i saw, the result is still same when use loop and goto. The array doesn't come out. only the last array display for three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be never to use `goto` statement in C , it really mess up the readability of your source code. Also, go through this link, [Why goto statement is not generally used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

Apart from this, you code can be simple re-written like this using [for-loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm) statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *a[3];
    char s[100];
    int data = 1, i;
    for(i=0; i<3 && data == 1; i++) {
      printf("Please insert name: ");
      scanf(" %s", &s);
      a[i] = s;
      printf("Do you want to add data?: ");
          scanf("%d", &data);
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
      printf("%s", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const char *a[3];
    char s[100];
    int data, i = 0, j;
    back: printf("Please insert name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &s);
    a[i] = s;
    printf("Do you want to add data?: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    i++;
    if (data == 1)
    {
        goto back;
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j = j + 1)
            printf("%s ", a[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the OP used label `back` and `goto back;`, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Also: This code is invalid and invokes undefined behaviour for various reasons! Your compiler should be crying, why do you ignore it? (I don't care if the errors are in the original, an answer should provide correct code)

Comment: Also same when using this code, when i print, only the last array appear for three times.